# PHP Single Sign On Active Directory

Tags: php, active-directory, ldap

I know there are similar questions about this but, I didn't know how to proceed.
I am running a PHP application under Apache on an Ubuntu machine. This application is basically an intranet application running under the same domain. 
The users are on Windows 7 and they login into the system with the credentails created in ldap server.
The users login into the php application with same credentials what they used to login into the system.

I need to do a single sign on for my application without prompting the login form.

Is there a way to have single sign on? If yes, can you please help me on how do I proceed?

Comment: You haven't mentioned what PHP software you're running, if there is existing LDAP authentication support for it, what the *other* sign-ons are using (SSO implies that multiple things use the same credentials).  You need to provide much more information before anyone will be able to answer a programming question like this.

Comment: Google for NTLM ldap auth with PHP.

Comment: The magic word you are looking for is "SSPI".  The Apache module is 'mod_auth_sspi'.  I discovered it recently while adding Remote Login support to my open source SSO Server/Client.

Answer (score 1):

This are some of the link that may be helpful for you.

http://rashidi.zin.my/geek-talks/2009/06/30/php-mysql-curl-single-sign-on-with-multiple-domains.html
http://www.opengroup.org/security/sso/sso_intro.htm
http://www.authenticationworld.com/Single-Sign-On-Authentication/
http://merbist.com/2012/04/04/building-and-implementing-a-single-sign-on-solution/
https://wiki.queensu.ca/display/itsd/Single+Sign-On
https://github.com/jasny/sso#readme
https://lw.microstrategy.com/msdz/MSDL/940/docs/mergedProjects/websdk/topics/sso/SSO_Single_Sign-on.htm